# How do I add a new member variable in PHP?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to do something like:

```
class Name{
    function assign($name,$value){
    }
}
```

Which is pretty much the same as `assign` in smarty:

```
$smarty->assign('name',$value);
$smarty->display("index.html");
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Name {
   private $values = array()

   function assign($name,$value) {
       $this->values[$name] = $value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question's a little vague. If you want to keep the $value of $name around for future use you could do something like:

```
class Name {

    protected $_data= array();

    function assign($name,$value) {
      $this->_data[$name]= $value;
    }
}
```

Then to make the variables available in an included template file:

```
class Templater {

    protected $_data= array();

    function assign($name,$value) {
      $this->_data[$name]= $value;
    }

    function render($template_file) {
       extract($this->_data);
       include($template_file);
    }
}

$template= new Templater();
$template->assign('myvariable', 'My Value');
$template->render('path/to/file.tpl');
```

And if path/to/file.tpl contains:

```
<html>
<body>
This is my variable: <b><?php echo $myvariable; ?></b>
</body>
</html>
```

You would get output like this

> This is my variable: **My Value**

Answer (score 1):

```
class Name{
    private $_vars;
    function __construct() {
        $this->_vars = array();
    }

    function assign($name,$value) {
        $this->_vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    function display($templatefile) {
        extract($this->_vars);
        include($templatefile);
    }
}
```

The `extract()` call temporarily pulls key-value pairs from an array into existence as variables named for each key with values corresponding to the array values.

Comment: Don't you mean `$this->_vars`?

Comment: Do you think this is MVC?I can see it separates View and Logic,but I don't know Modal and Control.Do you?

Comment: Usually where you'd *get* the data to pass to `assign()` would be from a model. Since there's no actual data being used here, you're only going to see elements of the view and the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
class Name{
    private $_values = array(); // or protected if you prefer
    function assign($name,$value){
       $this->_values[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This way only one variable can be assgigned.

Comment: you want to assign an array ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a global registry class to make your variables available to your HTML file:

```
class registry
{
     private $data = array();

     static function set($name, $value)
     {
          $this->data[$name] = $value;
     }

     static function get($value)
     {
           return isset($this->data[$name]) ? $this->data[$name] : false;
     }

}
```

And access like this from your files:

```
registry::get('my already set value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class XY
{

 public function __set($name, $value)
 {
      $this->$name = $value;
 }

 public function __get($value)
 {
       return isset($this->$name) ? $this->$name : false;
 }

}

$xy = new XY();

$xy->username = 'Anton';
$xy->email = 'anton{at}blabla.com';


echo "Your username is: ". $xy->username;
echo "Your Email is: ". $xy->email;
```