# How to implement display like smarty in PHP?

Tags: php, smarty, templating

```
$smarty->assign('name',$value);
$smarty->display("index.html");
```

So that it automatically replaces `$variables` in index.html which saves a lot of `echo`?

Comment: @Mask: some use have already implemented that on your last question....

Comment: @Mask: so go get a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761073/how-to-add-a-new-member-variable-in-php/1761094#1761094

Comment: Why don't you use smarty's `display`?

Comment: @RC: from my point of view he is recoding Smarty ...

Comment: @RageZ, I saw that too based on the replies in the question you pointed but I don't understand why..

Comment: @RageZ,seems your answer didn't provide the solution.

Comment: @Mask: see my answer which is a copy & paste from the code of an user of your previous question ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
// assigns the output of a file into a variable...
function get_include_contents($filename, $data='') {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            extract($data);
        }
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
    return false;
}


$data = array('name'=>'Ross', 'hobby'=>'Writing Random Code');
$output = get_include_contents('my_file.php', $data);
// my_file.php will now have access to the variables $name and $hobby
```

Answer (score 1):

taken from the previous question

```
class Templater {

    protected $_data= array();

    function assign($name,$value) {
      $this->_data[$name]= $value;
    }

    function render($template_file) {
       extract($this->_data);
       include($template_file);
    }
}

$template= new Templater();
$template->assign('myvariable', 'My Value');
$template->render('path/to/file.tpl');
```

in the template

```
<?= $foobar ?>
```

would print foobar .... if you need to make your own syntax you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://us.php.net/preg_replace_callback)

for example :

```
function replace_var($matches){
    global $data;
    return $data[$matches[1]];
}
preg_replace_callback('/{$([\w_0-9\-]+)}/', 'replace_var');
```

Comment: thanks to this user for the code http://stackoverflow.com/users/212700/unknown-google

Comment: Can someone understand how it replaces the variable of $myvariable here?I just don't see that part.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Templater class from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761073/how-to-add-a-new-member-variable-in-php/) you could change the render function to use regular expressions

```
function render($template_file) {
  $patterns= array();
  $values= array();
  foreach ($this->_data as $name=>$value) {
    $patterns[]= "/\\\$$name/";
    $values[]= $value;
  }
  $template= file_get_contents($template_file);
  echo preg_replace($patterns, $values, $template);
}

......

$templater= new Templater();
$templater->assign('myvariable', 'My Value');
$templater->render('mytemplate.tpl');
```

And the following template file:

```
<html>
<body>
This is my variable <b>$myvariable</b>
</body>
</html>
```

Would render:

> This is my variable **My Value**

Disclaimer: haven't actually run this to see if it works! See the PHP manual on preg_replace, example #2: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you describe is handled by the [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) php function, for example:

```
// Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php
$size = "large";
$var_array = array("color" => "blue", "size"  => "medium", "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");
echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";
```

But i would strongly advise you to use one of the classes posted by Sergey or RageZ since else you'll be reinventing the wheel, there are plenty of lowprofile and highend template classes available in PHP, to many actually :)